# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' after migration the project to 4.0 from 1.0 framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis, .net-framework-version

I have one project which is Developed in Web Forms 1.0 Framework know I migrate that product to 2010. Project is running well no errors. The issue i am facing is when i run the project it show me the error that the username and password is not correct when i use to login in Home page,The database is no other server

But when running same code by IIS server getting

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a new *Web Application* within IIS for this? If so, check that you have set **Anonymous Authentication** to **Enabled**. That is what that error sounds like it is indicating.

[image]

It could be a more complex issue, but a good thing to check.